# No map received in rviz

Tags: rviz, move-base, amcl, octomap, map-server

Iam trying to launch the amcl.launch file with MapServer node. and I have taken the map with octomap and want to visualize the map in 3d. so I have created a launch file for that. but i am getting error as "no map received" in rviz here is the launch file.

```
<launch>
```

```
<!-- Run Map Server for AMCL-->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server"
      args="$(find my_robot)/maps_lab/octomap_projection.yaml">
    
</node>

<!--- Run AMCL -->
<node name="amcl" pkg="amcl" type="amcl">
    <remap from="/scan" to="/pepper_robot/laser" />
    <param name="max_particles" value="100" />
    <param name="min_particles" value="50" />
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint" />
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="omni" />
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0" />
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0" />
    <param name="initial_pose_a" value="0" />
```

and here is the rostopic list

```
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/clock
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/initialpose
/joint_angles
/joint_states
/map
/move_base_simple/goal
/particlecloud
/pepper_robot/audio
/pepper_robot/bumper
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/camera_info
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom_rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/bottom_rectify_color/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/camera_info
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/image/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/points
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/camera_info
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/front/camera_info
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/front/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/front_rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/front_rectify_color/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressedDepth
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/ir_rectify_ir/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/ir_rectify_ir/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/camera_info
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw/compressed
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw/theora
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/pepper_robot/camera/stereo/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/pepper_robot/hand_touch
/pepper_robot/head_touch
/pepper_robot/imu/base
/pepper_robot/imu/torso
/pepper_robot/info
/pepper_robot/laser
/pepper_robot/odom
/pepper_robot/sonar/back
/pepper_robot/sonar/front
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/speech
/statistics
/tf
/tf_static
```

and here is the rqt_graph [image]

and here is the tf frames

> [tf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P300OTpoe9MMWaoblEOcYe8WmED78Pqz/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a configuration error, make sure these topics are working and publishing data with the correct frame ids:

```
/map
/pepper_robot/laser
/pepper_robot/odom
```

You can also check if your AMCL is doing the correct remappings and using the correct topics. From looking at the rqt_graph I can't see the laser topic connected to AMCL node. maybe check that? the map topic is also not visible?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked with the topics that you mentioned, Laser(pepper_robot/laser) and Odom(pepper_robot/odom) topics are publishing data but /map is not publishing the data and says : WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published? Also, I have checked the /laser topic and it is subscribed to amcl node.